# Getting Error in creating proxy classes for Client Console application to Consume WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding

I am working on WCF simple example of helloWorld and I can consume this service using WCF Test Client, however I am getting error while creating proxy classes for client application to consume this service

```
C:\My Work\My Development\WCFTestAPP\HelloWorldClient>  http://localhost:63859/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl /out:HelloWorldServiceRef.cs /config:app.config
'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

### Service

```
 [ServiceContract]
interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetMessage(string name);
}
```

### Service Side Implementation

```
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string GetMessage(string name)
    {
        return "Hello world from " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

### I have added asp.net webpage in project and update it web.config as

```
<configuration>

 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment >
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="~/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc" service="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you added the service reference in your client project?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the name of the program to run to generate the proxy - svcutil.  From a developer command prompt, try

```
svcutil http://localhost:63859/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl /out:HelloWorldServiceRef.cs /config:app.config
```

Comment: no I have added as;   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\SvcUtil.exe" 
  http://localhost:63859/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl /out:HelloWorldServiceRef.cs /config:app.config